# MySQL subquery select max value in secondary table with conditionals in both tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, max

There's a syntax issue I can't solve after looking at many "similar" problems in the stackoverflow database, e.g 7745609. Here the "unique" issue is that there's conditionals on each table. Here's my code:

```
    SELECT r.ID, r.FirstName, r.LastName, m.TotalMPs
    FROM roster r 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MPs m 
    ON r.ID= m.ID
    WHERE r.eMail IS NOT NULL AND r.Subscribe = "Y" AND r.Status = "A" AND m.TotalMPs <= "10" 
    ORDER BY r.LastName, r.FirstName
```

This retrieves all the rows in roster where the matching ID in MPs has TotalMPs <= 10. But there are multiple rows for an ID in MPs and I only want the MAX(TotalMPs) row from MPs "joined" to the single corresponding entry in roster. I've tried adding MAX() in various places and GROUP BY in LEFT OUTER JOIN clause but get syntax errors. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your dataset sample and what is more valuable your current result and your desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT r.ID, r.FirstName, r.LastName, m.TotalMPs
FROM roster r 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID, MAX(TotalMPs) as TotalMPs
    FROM MPs
    GROUP BY ID 
) m
ON r.ID = m.ID AND m.TotalMPs <= "10"
WHERE r.eMail IS NOT NULL 
AND r.Subscribe = "Y" 
AND r.Status = "A" 
ORDER BY r.LastName, r.FirstName
```

Comment: Thank you Alex! That is perfect.